# How to get the angle in the triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

See the following pictures:
∠DBC=13°,∠BCD=30°,∠DCA=73°,∠CAB=51°

∠ADB=?

[image: Find the value of ∠ADB=?]

Comment: what has been tried ( off to sleep here).

Answer (score 4):

Let $\measuredangle ADB=x$.

Thus, by law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{\sin\measuredangle DBA}{\measuredangle ADB}=\frac{\sin13^{\circ}}{\sin{x}},$$
$$\frac{AC}{AD}=\frac{\sin\measuredangle ADC}{\sin\measuredangle ACD}=\frac{\sin(223^{\circ}-x)}{\sin73^{\circ}}.$$
Thus, $$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{\sin13^{\circ}\sin(223^{\circ}-x)}{\sin{x}\sin73^{\circ}},$$
which gives
$$\frac{\sin13^{\circ}\sin(223^{\circ}-x)}{\sin{x}\sin73^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin26^{\circ}}{\sin103^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin13^{\circ}\sin(223^{\circ}-x)}{\sin{x}\sin73^{\circ}}=\frac{2\sin13^{\circ}\cos13^{\circ}}{\cos13^{\circ}}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin(x-43^{\circ})}{\sin{x}\sin73^{\circ}}=2$$ or
$$\frac{\sin{x}\cos43^{\circ}-\cos{x}\sin43^{\circ}}{\sin{x}}=2\sin73^{\circ}$$ or 
$$\cos43^{\circ}-\sin43^{\circ}\cot{x}=2\sin73^{\circ}$$ or
$$\cot{x}=\frac{\cos43^{\circ}-2\sin73^{\circ}}{\sin43^{\circ}}.$$
Now, $$\frac{\cos43^{\circ}-2\sin73^{\circ}}{\sin43^{\circ}}=\frac{\cos43^{\circ}-\cos17^{\circ}-\cos17^{\circ}}{\sin43^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{-2\sin13^{\circ}\sin30^{\circ}-\cos17^{\circ}}{\sin43^{\circ}}=-\frac{\sin13^{\circ}+\sin73^{\circ}}{\sin43^{\circ}}=$$
$$=-\frac{2\sin43^{\circ}\cos30^{\circ}}{\sin43^{\circ}}=-\sqrt3,$$

which gives  $x=150^{\circ}$.

Done!

Comment: $\measuredangle ADB$ was already labeled as $\theta$, by the way

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor I know, but to write $x$ is more comforting.

Comment: Haha! To each his own ;)

Comment: $$\frac{sin(x-43^{\circ})}{sinx\cdot sin73^{\circ}}=2$$
$$sin(x-43^{\circ}) = 2sinx\cdot sin(30^{\circ}+43^{\circ})$$
$$sinx\cdot cos43^{\circ}-cosx\cdot sin43^{\circ}=2sinx(\frac{cos43^{\circ}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}sin43^{\circ}}{2})$$
$$tanx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
Which gives $x=150^{\circ}$

Answer (score 2):

Pls see the picture as follows:

[image]

Assume $\overline{CD}=2$, we have:
$$\frac{sin\alpha}{sin\beta}=2\bullet cos17^{\circ}$$

But: $$\alpha+\beta=51^{\circ}=3\bullet 17^{\circ}$$

So, we have: $\alpha=2\beta=2\times 17^{\circ}$, which is the only solution.

because the equation :$sin\alpha=2cos17^{\circ}\cdot sin(51^{\circ}-\alpha)$, left side is increasing function and right side is decreasing function, so there is only ONE solution in $(0,51^{\circ})$.

which gives $\theta=180^{\circ}-(13^{\circ}+17^{\circ}) = 150^{\circ}$